# How to run php function at specific time?

Tags: php

I'm making a small browser game where you can send troops to attack other players. I need the server to run a php script when an attack hits the opponent. It needs to be within a second from the hit. I have considered using windows scheduler, but you can only make it update at 1 minute interval. The time when the update needs to happen is only shown after the attack has been sent manually by the player, so I'm not sure if any interval system would work.

Is there a way to do this or should I just look for a workaround?

Comment: Maybe PHP is not the right language to do that, NodeJS looks like better for what you want to do.

Comment: If its a client side game, cant you use AJAX to call the .php script

Comment: sleep()   http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php

Comment: Use jquery `setInterval ()` function to call the function peroidically then make ajax request to run your php script

Comment: I am using ajax, but the poblem is when the players are not at the computer, the game should run in the background anyway. I have been dealing with this by running the functions at the order of arrival time, and it works, but there are few other tables that needs to do the same. I just thought if there were better way.

Comment: maybe ajax + some queue  (for example https://www.rabbitmq.com/ )? Ajax sends  data to rabbit , and some other part of your game process it  ?